# Construction of Circles in Book I, Proposition 2 of The Elements

Tags: geometry

Here is an excerpt of Book I, Proposition 2:

[image]

[image]

---

I know that Euclid is not totally rigorous in the modern sense, and making geometry rigorous has never been an easy task, but I'm wondering how to best "rigorize" the construction of the circle $CGH$. My problem with the above is that the circle $CGH$ is defined without any specific reference to what the points $G$ and $H$ should be... yet it is clear from the diagram that a certain $G$ is intended - namely, the one which is on the line extended from $DB$. One way I thought would be to reverse the construction of the circle and the line $BF$ which it intersects. Here's what I'm thinking:

> Let the circle $\mathfrak{C}$ with center $B$ and radius $BC$ be drawn. Now, either the point $D$ lies within the circle $\mathfrak{C}$ or it does not. If it does, then if the line segment $DB$ is extended in a straight line, it must intersect the circle at some point. $^{[1]}$ If $D$ does not lie within the circle, then $DB$ intersects the circle at some point. $^{[2]}$ In either case, call this point of intersection $G$.

To be clear, I'm simply **looking for some guidance on how one might make this construction rigorous**... or why one shouldn't bother. I know this is at least partly a matter of opinion, so feel free to give your own take on this issue and similar issues re: "The Elements vs. rigor" in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem of rigor in the construction of the circle. It is defined in terms of the known point $B$ and the known line $BC$, and $CGH$ is the name of the circle. The real question of rigor is why the circle intersects $DF$, something which Euclid's stated axioms don't justify. He seems to be implicitly using the principle that a segment extended from a point (to wit, $B$) within a circle will eventually intersect that circle. We could try to patch things up by adding more axioms. But really, there are enough things like this in the Elements that if you're bothered about them, you might as well redo the theory from the ground up. One book doing this is Edwin Moise's *Elementary Geometry from an Advanced Standpoint*.